# User Management System approach for Group and Firm

Tags: php, mysql, user-management

I am creating a User Management System and need your advice.

3 entities:

1. Users
2. Firm
3. Group

Each `user` will belong to one `Firm`.
Some users (not all) may belong to `Group`.
`Group` is a combination of `Firms`. (E.g. 3 firms in a group)

The data will be displayed according to user's `firm` or `group`, if a `user` belongs to `firm` (but not `group`), then `firm` level data will be displayed. And if the `user` belong to `group` then `group` level data (e.g. 3 firms' data) will be displayed.

Is my below mentioned approach correct for this purpose:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_account` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firm` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, # each user belong to a client firm
  `group` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, # some users may belong to client group
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
  `username` varchar(15) NOT NULL, # USER ID
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `account_creation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `token_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, # for password recovery
  `token_creation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL, # for password recovery
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username_UNIQUE` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `permission` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, # FOREIGN KEY user_account.user_name
  `association` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, # Firm or Group
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: It's not how I'd do it. Users belong to firms. Firms belong to groups. Can a firm belong to more than one group? And note the group is a reserved word, which makes it a infuriating choice for a table/column identifier

Comment: You're probably wise to design this using entities (people, firms, groups) and relationships. You can read about that. You may find the MySQL workbench to be a useful design tool. **Pro tip** you can't be too careful when desiging your tables. Every minute of effort you take getting a good design will save you hours when programming.

Comment: @Strawberry you're right about `group`. The schema I'm working with these days has a table with that name. Drives me crazy.  *Almost* crazy enough to go all Hungarian calling it `group_t` .

Comment: @Strawberry Every firm belongs to certain Group but one firm can not belong to more than one group. If this is not how you'd do it then what's the best approach in your opinion?

Comment: Essentially: A table of users and a table of firms.

Comment: @Strawberry Is that all? Does that mean I don't need `permission` table? Do I need a table for `group` as well?

Comment: Some of the prefixes have been omitted for the sake of privacy, so `group` column is not really just `group`.